# Which assumption is less plausible, "action at a distance", or that "virtual particles" can exist for a short time?

Tags: vacuum, virtual-particles

It is understood that virtual particle appear in Feynman diagrams as a tool of calculus. And it is understood that they are problematic about their mass, and cannot be detected (is that sure indeed?).

But, what alternative is left for conveying to one charged particle that at some distance exists another charged particle?
Is the "action-at-a-distance" a plausible alternative? 
It seems that it is a WORSE one: a type of action-at-a-distance is needed for electrostatic field between charges of the same sign, and another type for opposite sign, and another type for gravitational. It seems that we have a couple of types of vacuum, for each type of force, a type of vacuum with its action-at-a-distance.

Please don't indicate reference to other questions. I ask for an answer to THIS question - what is LESS plausible?

Comment: It is worth recalling that "virtual particles" are a way of talking about the terms in a series that arises when using second quantization of *fields* to compute interactions. That is "virtual particles" are fields. And there are a *lot* of reasons to like fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtual particles are far more plausible because of experimental results such as the [Casimir Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) which is non classical and predicted as a consequence of the "reality" of virtual particles.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between the apparently three types of particles: (1) virtual particles, (2) real particles, and (3) "real" virtual particles?

Comment: Anything "virtual" cannot be directly detected. Only its effects observed.

Comment: So we do not know, if the effects we find are caused by "this thing" or something completely else, right?

Comment: Right - we cannot prove the Casimir effect is not made by microscopic invisible unicorns. It's just that the maths is more plausible.

Comment: The maths predicting the Casimir effect turned out to be extremely wrong, so to me the concept of virtual particles exerting real forces is on the par of invisible unicorns. Especially if one is aware of the vacuum catastrophe that results from accepting the same postulates as the explanation of the Casimir effect.

Comment: You think the maths predicting the casimir effect is wrong? Even though it gives the correct answer in its domain of applicability?

Comment: The maths gave the wrong answer. Very wrong. And it still does. That's why it needs to be "regularized". (You might want to follow your own link.)

Comment: I don't see a problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Derivation_of_Casimir_effect_assuming_zeta-regularization 

I assume you don't like "mathematical tricks"?

Comment: "I don't see a problem". I believe you.